# Avoiding ng-include while allowing flexibility in rendering sub-templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, templates

I have a component which is treated like a "blog post" for example.  A single piece of content that contains data.  I've created a bunch of templates that can be rendered using ng-include in my "blog" template.

**A few examples:**

- Blog content (title, author, etc.)
- Related Posts
- Author information
- Email signup
- (Any infinite number of possibilities)

I can't hardcode these into the template for a few reasons.

1. Each section needs to be able to be presented in any order (order dependent upon JSON)
2. All of these options need to be optional

Normally I would use some kind of foreach loop in the angular template and conditionally load each template via ng-include, but I've read this could have a major performance hit.

What's the best way to approach this using Angular 1.6.4 and components?

Comment: Think I would rewrite each ng-include into components and iterate the json in a for loop and finally use ng-if to trigger the right component

Answer (score 0):

What about using a function to decide which template to include?  This is a very generic example.

```
<div ng-include="vm.getTemplate(myVar)">

</div>
```

function

```
vm.getTemplate = function(myVar) {
   //logic to decide template
   return '../templates/someTemplate.html';
}
```